# Why does concatenating two non constant expression empty strings result in an interned empty string?

Tags: java, string

`empty() + empty() == ""` is true locally on eclipse, false on Intellij and I don't understand why?

```
public static String empty() {
        return "";
}
public static String a() {
        return "a";
}

empty() + empty() == "" // true???, locally on eclipse but not in an online compiler jdoodle.com/ia/kTI or intellij
a() + a() == "aa" // false 
"a" + empty() == "a"  // false
empty() + "a" == "a" // false
```

JDK version both online and locally (eclipse and IntelliJ)  are 17.0.1.

To be clear, I know what string interning is. My question is why the result of the addition at runtime is getting interned locally (which is surprising) and why it's not online (on the same jdk version).

Comment: It's best to assume that when you're doing `==` on strings, it's implemented by a tiny demon who hates you.  That's why you don't do it, and also shouldn't care what it does.

Comment: What do you expect the result of adding two empty strings together to be?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Poetic.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would've expected it to create a new String. and thus be false. But it seems to not do.  I was surprised and went to try it online. and was left even more surprised since it was false there.

Comment: Looks like in some implementations, `+` is special-cased to avoid allocation for empty strings.

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but isn't JDK the implementation? and since it's the same version. Something else should also be happening no?

Comment: @Louis: Look at the duplicate question linked at the top of this post.  It explains why it's not two strings.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's not a duplicate question. I know what string interning is. my question is why does it happen in this case. (concatenation at runtime locally) and why does it not happen online (concatenation at runtime locally) on the same jdk version.

Comment: @RobertHarvey to explain more, normally for other strings like "a", " ", "hello".  The result of concatenation at runtime does not get interned (neither locally or online)

Comment: Then I agree with @LouisWasserman.  Empty string is apparently treated as a special case.

Comment: By the way, this is a perfect example why you should never use `==` instead of `.equals()` to compare two strings.  The results are almost always not what you want.